# In LDS canon, is the Final Judgement before or after the resurrection?

Tags: lds, resurrection, judgment

I've always understood the Final Judgment to occur just before the resurrection because the judgement determines which glory you are resurrected to. The Gospel Principles lesson on the [Final Judgement](https://www.lds.org/manual/gospel-principles/chapter-46-the-final-judgment?lang=eng) seems to imply that also. It makes sense because we are to be resurrected to a glory, but that glory is dependent on the outcome of our judgement.

However I was reading in [2 Nephi 9](https://www.lds.org/scriptures/bofm/2-ne/9?lang=eng) this morning where it says that the resurrection comes before judgment.

> 13 O how great the plan of our God! For on the other hand, the
>   paradise of God must deliver up the spirits of the righteous, and the
>   grave deliver up the body of the righteous; and the spirit and the
>   body is restored to itself again, and all men become incorruptible,
>   and immortal....
>
> 15 And it shall come to pass that when all men shall have passed from
>   this first death unto life, insomuch as they have become immortal,
>   they must appear before the judgment-seat of the Holy One of Israel;
>   and then cometh the judgment, and then must they be judged according
>   to the holy judgment of God.

There in verse 13 it says that the spirit and body are reunited (resurrection) and so we become immortal. Then in verse 15 it says that ***after*** we become immortal (resurrected) we will be judged.

So which is it? Does the judgment occur before or after the resurrection?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Alma 40, it also states:

> 21 But whether it be at his [Christ's] resurrection or after, I do not say; but
>   this much I say, that there is a space between death and the
>   resurrection of the body, and a state of the soul in happiness or in
>   misery until the time which is appointed of God that the dead shall
>   come forth, and be reunited, both soul and body, and be brought to
>   stand before God, and be judged according to their works.

Which means, the final judgement is after the resurrection.

But remember also that the resurrection of the unjust is later than the resurrection of the just:

Doctrine and Covenants 76:63-65 (speaking of celestial glory)

> 63 These are they whom he shall bring with him, when he shall come in
>   the clouds of heaven to reign on the earth over his people.
>
> 64 These are they who shall have part in the first resurrection.
>
> 65 These are they who shall come forth in the resurrection of the
>   just.

Doctrine and Covenants 76:85 (speaking of telestial glory)

> 85 These are they who shall not be redeemed from the devil until the
>   last resurrection, until the Lord, even Christ the Lamb, shall have
>   finished his work.

So, yes, we are judged after we have been resurrected, and how that judgement is going to turn out determines when it happens (along with the resurrection of that individual). That makes perfect sense given the divine mercy, since that way the individual gets as much time as possible to repent, up until the appointed time of the Final Judgement.

So, both things you said are true (judgement determines how and when we are resurrected, but resurrection happens before the judgement), but as an event, resurrection happens before the judgement. Maybe the confusion clears if we settle with the following formulation: Our actions (and motives etc. and not forgetting this is only possible due to divine grace) determine when we are resurrected, how we are resurrected, and what the outcome of the judgement will be.

Comment: Just noticed that the [Guide to the Scriptures](https://www.lds.org/scriptures/gs/judgment-the-last?lang=eng) says "The final judgment that will occur after the resurrection."

Answer (score 2):

We believe that when we die, our spirits are sent to a place call the "Spirit World." Here there is a separation from those who have received the Gospel and those who haven't (Spirit Paradise / Spirit Prison) ([Alma 40:12-14](https://www.lds.org/scriptures/bofm/alma/40.12-14?lang=eng#11), [1 Peter 4:6](https://www.lds.org/scriptures/nt/1-pet/4.6?lang=eng#5), [1 Peter 3:18-20](https://www.lds.org/scriptures/nt/1-pet/3.18-20?lang=eng#17)). This is a judgement, but not the final one.  Those who are in Spirit Prison still have the opportunity to change and repent before the Final Judgement.

The Final Judgement is where we will stand before God to give an accounting of the way we lived our life and used our time.  We will be resurrected prior to the Final Judgement.

[2 Nephi 9](https://www.lds.org/scriptures/bofm/2-ne/9?lang=eng) answers your question, and so have you.

- Verse 12-13 speaks of the resurrection (becoming immortal)
- Verse 15 speaks of the judgement (after becoming immortal)

So your question `Does the judgment occur before or after the resurrection?` was answered within your question.

> There in verse 13 it says that the spirit and body are reunited (resurrection) and so we become immortal. Then in verse 15 it says that ***after*** we become immortal we will be judged.

I am not sure where the Gospel Principles Book implies the Final Judgement will happen before the resurrection.  I skimmed it today, and have studied it in the past, and if you look at additional scriptures at the bottom you will see this:

> Alma 11:41, 45; Mormon 7:6; 9:13–14 (we are judged in a resurrected state)

Just to reiterate, the LDS Canon teaches Resurrection is prior to the Final Judgement.

Answer (score 1):

The answers given are correct. I would just add one thought. Given that resurrection can be defined as the "inseparable union of body and spirit" (See Alma 11:45 & D&C 138:17), and that the resurrected body will accord with the respective degree of glory obeyed (See D&C 88:28-32), it is clear that the resurrection itself is the judgement - the final judgement is a formal ceremony similar to a college graduation - the work and grade are actually known. It is an important formality - but a formality nonetheless.